# How to replace an entire column with a for loop function?

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter, jupyter-lab

```
input = '18.7m, 17.7m, 11.1m, 9.3m, 6.9m, 9.9m, 4.4m, 1.8m, 7.9m'

multipliers = {'k': 1e3,
               'm': 1e6,
              }

pattern = r'([0-9.]+)([km])'
for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, input):
    number = float(number)
    print(number * multipliers[suffix])
    
for views in df_tiktok: #THIS IS WHERE I GET STUCK
```

I want to apply this for loop to a few columns containing variables such as '18.7M, 17.7M, and 645.1k'. Basically, I would like to apply the above for loop to these columns.

| Views avg. | Likes avg | Comments avg. | Shares avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 18.7M | 2.6M | 54.7K |
| 6 | 17.7M | 2.3M | 18K |

FIRST ATTEMPT:

```
likes_avg = [[likes] for likes in tiktok_data]
if 'K' in likes :
        like=likes.strip('K')
        like=float(like)*1000
        likes_avg.append(round(like))
if 'M' in likes :
        like=likes.strip('M')
        like=float(like)*1000000
        likes_avg.append(round(like))
```

SECOND ATTEMPT:

```
input = '18.7m, 17.7m, 11.1m, 9.3m, 6.9m, 9.9m, 4.4m, 1.8m, 7.9m'

multipliers = {'k': 1e3,
               'm': 1e6,
              }

pattern = r'([0-9.]+)([km])'
for number, suffix in re.findall(pattern, input):
    number = float(number)
    print(number * multipliers[suffix])
```

Comment: What language is this? Python? Or something else? You need to add the tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a lot by creating a function

```
def modify(input):
    if isinstance(input, int) or isinstance(input,float)  :
        return input
    if 'K' in input:
      return  float(input.replace('K',''))*1000
    elif 'M' in input:
      return  float(input.replace('M',''))*1000000
    else:
        return input
```

Then apply this modify function on each column of your df

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c]= df[c].apply(lambda x: modify(x))
```

This is what I get after testing

```
for c in df.columns:
  df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: modify(x))
```

Output

```
    Views avg.   Likes avg  Comments avg.  Shares avg
0               3  18700000.0      2600000.0     54700.0
1               6  17700000.0      2300000.0     18000.0
```

Or you can use applymap for entire df

```
df.applymap(lambda x: modify(x))
Out[259]: 
       Views avg.   Likes avg  Comments avg.  Shares avg
0               3  18700000.0      2600000.0     54700.0
1               6  17700000.0      2300000.0     18000.0
```